# Need a CouchDB trick to sort by date and filter by group

Tags: view, dictionary, couchdb, mapreduce

I have documents with fields 'date' and 'group'. And this is my view:

```
byDateGroup: {
  map: function(doc) {
    if (doc.date && doc.group) {
      emit([doc.date, doc.group], null);
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the equivalent query of this:

```
select * from docs where group in ("group1", "group2") order by date desc
```

This simple solution is not coming into my head. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pankaj, switch the order of the key you're emitting to this:

```
emit([doc.group, doc.date], doc);
```

Then you can pass in a start key and an end key when querying the view.  It might be easier to do a separate query for each group that you want to pull data for.  The data will be sorted by date.

I'm on my way out at the moment, but can elaborate more when I get back if it isn't clear.

Comment: +1 This seems like the best solution. Fundamentally, Jangid is asking for a join and so multiple requests and "joining" back at the client is probably the most straightforward thing.

Comment: Agreed. This is the best available approach at the moment. In addition to what @JasonSmith said, you could also do the additional filtering in a _list function. In all cases, CouchDB will "auto order by" all your date keys (timestamps or date arrays). The "hard part" is just picking out the specific groups from the index.

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.date && ["group1", "group2"].indexOf(doc.group) !== -1)) {
    emit([doc.date, doc.group], null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a specific view for this:

```
byDateGroup1Group2: {
  map: function(doc) {
    if (doc.date && doc.group && (doc.group === "group1" || doc.group === "group2") {
      emit(doc.date, doc);
    }
  }
}
```

that you query (presumably in a list function) with query `descending=true`.